# How to manage job dependency in cluster deploy mode

Tags: apache-spark

When i submit a spark job using cluster mode, it returns immediately. And runs the job on cluster.

So if i want to submit Job B when job A complete suceessfully, it seems can't be done in cluster deploy mode. Because there is not any callbacks or notifications when job A completes.

Comment: If you have a dependency on job A, and job B should start only after job  A is finished, It would be better if you use Oozie as job scheduler. It is a wildly used tool to manage multiple job dependencies and scheduling. Here is the link. http://oozie.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

Except for what Apurba said, you can also write the dependency relations in your own program, by doing this, you can run a few jobs in one program.

Comment: If write job dependecies in program, it seems not very flexible.

Comment: It depends how you implement it. In this way, it'll be better if you store the dependencies in databases or configuration centers.  Of course you can use the job schedular like Azkaban and Oozie, but there is cost of deploying and maintaining. From my perspective, either way is good if it can fit your business well.